# Facebook accountKit debug mode, Change UI color and SMS Message content

Tags: android, account-kit

I already implemented the facebook accountKit in my android application. They have nice documentation in their official page. That's link is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android) for documentation and [here](https://github.com/fbsamples/account-kit-samples-for-android) is sample code.
currently i am fetching some issue. Those are given bellow:

1. **Change UI from facebook webpanel**: I already customized the apps UI from web panel. But this design is not affected in my application. My application is in development mode.
2. **Change SMS message body**: Currently in SMS body is like:

> USE 123456 as your login code for SOME_APPS [DEV MODE]. (Account Kit
>   by Facebook)

But why this message "DEV MODE" word? When and how it will reduce?
Some notes:

1. Currently i am in development mode. So may be it will resolved when i release this apps. But how i add [RELEASE MODE] for accountKit project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make some comments before giving down votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It sounds like you are following the web customization on the developer portal. To customize the UI for Android, you'll need to follow these docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android/customizing
2. The [DEV MODE] will be removed once your app is no longer in development mode.

Answer (score 0):

For the colors: you change the colors in the style Account kit had you add in the setup process. So it will look something like this:

```
<style name="AppLoginTheme" parent="Theme.AccountKit">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_background_color">@color/white</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_button_background_color">@color/acct_kit_blue</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_button_border_color">@color/acct_kit_transparent_color_off</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_button_text_color">@color/white</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_input_background_color">@color/acct_kit_light_grey</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_input_border_color">@color/acct_kit_transparent_color_off</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_input_text_color">@color/acct_kit_grey</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_primary_text_color">@color/acct_kit_grey</item>
</style>
```